# Revalidate key in Next.js

Tags: next.js

As you know, we can update SSG page via `revalidate` key in `getStaticProps()` and user at firstly see latest content and after refresh page twice can see updated content.

But is it proper that user should refresh page twice? In my opinion, user do not know should refresh twice. However, new users can see the new content at first.

I would be appreciate if share your comments about `revalidate`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually have more than 1 user. The Re-generation can be triggered by any of your users so not everyone on the site needs to refresh twice. Only 1 user would do that.